# Express js , Redis realtime updates

Tags: javascript, express

How to handle realtime changes from redis in Express js ? (Every time when there is some change in redis express needs to have fresh data) . Does anyone have good example how to do this ?

Comment: See http://socket.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis does support pub/sub. So here's an example using this driver:

https://github.com/mranney/node_redis

First when you change something you notify Redis, for example:

```
var redis = require("redis"),
    client = redis.createClient();

client.set("key", "value", function() {
    client.publish("notification channel", JSON.stringify({"key": "value"}));
});
```

and now you can do this:

```
var redis = require("redis"),
    client = redis.createClient();

client.subscribe("notification channel");

client.on("message", function(channel, msg) {
    if (channel === "notification channel") {
        var obj = JSON.parse(msg);
        // you now know what happend
    }
});
```

Just make sure that `.publish` fires whenever you update Redis.